# Accessing matrix rows and column in C++ with eigen

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

Let's say I have a matrix in C++:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <Eigen/Dense>  

using namespace Eigen;  

 int main()  
 {  
   Matrix4d a;  
   a << 1, 2, 3, 4;  
        5, 6, 7, 8;
        9, 10, 11, 12;
        13, 14, 15, 16;
 }
```

How do I go about utilizing the C++ Eigen library to manipulate a single row or column?
I am basically trying to replicate the MATLAB command: a(:,3) or a(3,:) etc...

Answer (score 1):

When using the `eigen` library to create a `matrix`, you can simply use either:

The `matrix.col()` function to change the column in the given `matrix`

The `matrix.row()` function to change the rows in the given `matrix`.

Individual columns or rows are cases of blocks.

Here is an example:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
 
 
int main()
{
  Eigen::MatrixXf a(3,3);
  a << 1,2,3,
       4,5,6,
       7,8,9;
  std::cout << "Here is the matrix:" << std::endl << a<< std::endl;
  std::cout << "Here is the third row: " << a.row(2) << std::endl;
  a.col(1) += 2 * a.col(0);
  std::cout << "Adding 2 times the first column into the second column. Now the matrix will be:\n";
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
 return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

... sorry figured this out.
simply use matrix.col() or matrix.row()

ezpz